# How to find the linkedSeries in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to make a plot with several time series using Highcharts. Some series are linked together, so when I click on the legend, the linked series will repose as I want. This feature can be done easily in Highcharts by default. But what I wanted is when I click on the legend, all other series will be hidden, and only the series selected, together with its linked series still be shown. E.g. there are series a, b and c, b is linked to a, when click on the legend of a, I want a and b keep showing, and c will be hidden, anybody has a clue?

jsfiddle.net/tianhuidong/qZpKN/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) and define what should be done after click. In your case you can decide which series shoudld be show/hidden.